# The "Oldest" answer

Tags: discussion, answers

Assume  that a  given  question has several  answers.

So in  the  answer part  there  are  3  button  "Active", "Oldest"  and  "Vote"

When we  clique on "oldest", we lead to  a unique  answer.

Is  this unique  answer  the  first  answer  to the  question?

I  doubt that the  answer to this meta question is  affirmative  since  it  does  not work for  example on this  question

[Finding a 1-form adapted to a smooth flow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow)

On the  other hand the  situation is  different  for  the  following  question with several answers

[If $x_{n+1}= \frac{nx_{n}^2+1}{n+1}$ then $x_{n}=1$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278590/if-x-n1-fracnx-n21n1-then-x-n-1?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

So  what  does "oldest"  signify?

Comment: meta.SE: [Ordering of answers for a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127231) and [Accepted answer shouldn't be sorted to the top when sorting by Newest or Oldest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7792). BTW your question seems to me closer to ([meta-tag:support]) than to ([meta-tag:discussion]). (And I don't really see why it is tagged ([meta-tag:moderators]), but maybe I missed something.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak  Thank you  for  the  link. i remove  the  "moderator" tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oldest does sort by the answer time, however, the accepted answer will still be on top, even if it is not the oldest; the same applies to the other sort options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.